Spectral theory: a key to unlocking efficient insights in network datasets
In the context of directed or undirected graphs, matrices such as adjacency and Laplacian matrices are commonly used. The eigenbasis of these matrices addresses some practical implications, such as centrality measures (like PageRank), and it is also crucial for clustering (community detection).

Q. What other practical implications have been identified in the literature by analyzing the eigenbasis?


Cross posted.

In any case, I think this question would benefit from removing some of the buzzwords from the title.

A place to find a wealth of examples is in graph signal processing, where spectral decomposition of the Laplacian is known as the graph Fourier transform.

A. Ortega, Introduction to Graph Signal Processing. Cambridge (2022), chapter 3 for the GFT and chapter 7 for examples.

Spectral graph theoretic examples are discussed in various places for example:

Van De Ville, Dimitri, Robin Demesmaeker, and Maria Giulia Preti. "When Slepian meets Fiedler: Putting a focus on the graph spectrum." IEEE Signal Processing Letters 24:7 (2017): 1001-1004.

This finds applications in graph and convolution based machine learning, and neuroimaging/brain connectivity, and perhaps as a illustrative example on road traffic data.

Stanković, Ljubiša, et al. "Vertex-frequency graph signal processing:
A comprehensive review." Digital signal processing 107 (2020):
102802.

There is also work in TDA and Applied Topology/Persistence along these lines such as persistent laplacians:

Mémoli, Facundo, Zhengchao Wan, and Yusu Wang. "Persistent Laplacians: Properties, algorithms and implications." SIAM Journal on Mathematics of Data Science 4.2 (2022): 858-884.

There are applications in protein engineering, covid variant forcasting and genomics.

Wei, Xiaoqi, and Guo-Wei Wei. "Persistent Topological Laplacians--a
Survey." arXiv preprint arXiv:2312.07563 (2023).

